IPython / ipdb auto-complete not working for arguments to p and pp commands
I'm using python 3.12.1, IPython 8.28.0, ipdb 0.13.13 and jedi 0.19.1 on ubuntu, started like this:
ipython --no-banner --pdb my_source_code.py

I have PYTHONBREAKPOINT set to ipdb.set_trace and when I encounter a breakpoint() I end up in an interactive debugger.
In general it works great, but at some point I noticed what I think is a regression. If I type, for example, pp myfun and then press TAB I'd expect auto-complete to suggest relevant symbols like myfunction (assuming it exists). I'm pretty sure it used to to this, but with the above versions (which should be the latest) it isn't working.
If I type !myfun and press TAB it works as expected. So I think the issue has to do with auto-completing command arguments.
